# React Transfer internal prop of Parent to Child

Tags: reactjs, jsx

```
<Parent><!-- has an internal prop 'json', is set from a fetch request -->
  <div>
    <div>
       <Child /><!-- how can I send 'json here? -->
```

Do I have to use React context? I find it very confusing. After writing a component like that and looking back at the code I am just confused https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: What do you mean by "internal prop" ? Please show how it is set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://codesandbox.io/embed/bold-bardeen-4n66r?fontsize=14

Have a look at the code, context is not that necessary you can elevate data to parent component, update it and share it from there only.

Comment: I like this because it's pretty straight forward, easy to read and suits my particular case but I think if you start having a lot of different children deep down in the tree then you have to pass the prop from every parent level it becomes an unmaintainable mess, then React context like I linked earlier better I think. So I am going to accept this answer but people please take this into account. It might not suit your particular need!

Comment: Yeah, If we have so many hierarchical structure then it's better to use Context.

Answer (score 1):

For what I know, there are 3 or 4 alternatives:

1) Using context as you said, so declaring a provider and then consuming it with `useContext()` at the component where you need it. It may reduce reusability of components,

2) Lift state & props, among descendant components

```
const App = (props: any) => {
// Do some stuff here
return <Parent myProp={props.myProp}></Parent>;
};

const Parent = ({ myProp }: any) => {
return (
    <div>
    <Child myProp={myProp}></Child>
    </div>
);
};

const Child = ({ myProp }: any) => {
return (
    <div>
    <GrandChild myProp={myProp}></GrandChild>{" "}
    </div>
);
};

const GrandChild = ({ myProp }: any) => {
return <div>The child using myProp</div>;
};

export default App;
```

3) Using children:

```
const App = (props: any) => {
// Do some stuff here
return (
    <Parent>
    <GrandChild myProp={props.myProp}></GrandChild>
    </Parent>
);
};

const Parent = (props: any) => {
return (
    <div>
    <Child>{props.children}</Child>
    </div>
);
};

const Child = (props: any) => {
return <div>{props.children}</div>;
};

const GrandChild = ({ myProp }: any) => {
return <div>The child using myProp</div>;
};
```

4) Pass the GrandChild itself as a prop in the Parent, lifting it down to the proper Child and render it there. It's actually a mix of the previous 2 alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple example where you send the response through props to child. I used some sample ([api](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/)) to demonstrate it.

------------------------Parent Component------------------------

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Axios from "axios";
import Child from "./Child";

let clicked = false;
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    parentResponse: ""
  };
  fetchAPI = () => {
    Axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
      .then(res => {
        if (res && res.data) {
          console.log("Res data: ", res.data);
          this.setState({ parentResponse: res.data });
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log("Failed to fetch response.");
      });
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchAPI();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Child parentResponse={this.state.parentResponse} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

------------------------Child Component------------------------

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Child extends Component {
  state = {};
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.parentResponse !== "" ? (
          <div>{this.props.parentResponse.title}</div>
        ) : (
          <div />
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Child;
```